# Some properties of my JSON response are not loading into my model

Tags: ios, foundation, decodable

I am getting the following error while accessing few properties my JSON response

> valueNotFound(Swift.String, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [CodingKeys(stringValue: "articles", intValue: nil), _JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 15", intValue: 15), CodingKeys(stringValue: "urlToImage", intValue: nil)], debugDescription: "Expected String value but found null instead.", underlyingError: nil))

In the following JSON response, I am getting above error for author, urlToimage & Content etc. I am not able to find out the reason for it.

```
"author": "PTI",
"title": "Rape Survivor, Set Ablaze in UP's Unnao a Day Ago, Critical; Doctors Say Her Vitals Are 'Very Low' - News18",
"description": "The Delhi Traffic Police on Thursday provided a 'green corridor' for hindrance-free movement of the ambulance carrying her from the airport to the hospital.",
"url": "https://www.news18.com/news/india/rape-survivor-set-ablaze-in-ups-unnao-a-day-ago-on-ventilator-at-delhi-hosp-docs-say-shes-critical-2414083.html",
"urlToImage": "https://images.news18.com/ibnlive/uploads/2019/12/Safdarjung-hospital-Unnao-rape.jpg",
"publishedAt": "2019-12-06T05:58:00Z",
"content": "New Delhi: The rape survivor from Unnao, who was airlifted to Delhi and admitted to the Safdarjung Hospital here, is extremely critical and on ventilator, doctors attending to her said on Friday.
"The condition of the patient is extremely critical and she is… [+1187 chars]"
```

I am using the following struct model.

```
struct Article: Decodable {

    let author: String
    let title: String
    let description: String
    let urlToImage: String
    let publishedAt: String
    let content: String
}
```

Please help me with this.

Comment: You need show us how you are parsing your JSON.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please **read** the error message carefully.

It clearly states that in the 16th item (***`JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 15", intValue: 15)`***) in the array `articles` (***`CodingKeys(stringValue: "articles"`***) there is no value (***`valueNotFound / Expected String value but found null instead`***) for key `urlToImage` (***`CodingKeys(stringValue: "urlToImage"`***)

Declare `urlToImage` in the struct as optional

```
let urlToImage: String?
```

Side note:

You can declare `url` and `urlToImage` as `URL` without any changes and `publishedAt` as `Date` by adding the `iso8601` date decoding strategy.